# JavaScript to auto-select a value works in the Firefox console but not in Greasemonkey script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, greasemonkey

I just want to auto-select a value in a form.

The following codes work in Firebug or the Firefox console but they do not work in a Greasemonkey userscript:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[2].contentWindow.document.getElementById("CDYN_126").value=1;
```

Or:

```
window.frames["WA2"].document.getElementById("CDYN_126").value = 1;
```

I also tried `setTimeout` and `waitForKeyElements` but nothing worked.

This is how I tried waitForKeyElements:

```
function deneme.(){
    $("#WA2").contents().filter("#CDYN_126").val('1');
}

waitForKeyElements ("#WA2", deneme);
```

**The relevant, rendered, HTML** looks like this:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" name="WA2" id="WA2" class="SCPIFRAMEMozilla">
    ...
    <select class="COMBOFIXSelectEdit" name="CC" id="CDYN_126" tabindex="1">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="1">Ithal Ürün</option>
        <option value="2">Yerli Ürün</option>
        <option value="3">Güncellenecek</option>
    </select>
    ...
</iframe>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show the page (or at least enough HTML to allow us to choose a selector) and show your attempt with `waitForKeyElements`.  That will work if you used the correct parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The console has elevated permissions, including access to child frames that aren't necessarily from the same origin as the parent page.

Userscripts, however, do not have that priviledge and therefore cannot access an iframe's contents unless it comes from the same protocol, hostname and port number.

You should be seeing an error message in your console telling you that.

Comment: iframe contents come from same origin. there is no error message in console

Answer (score 0):

The script is not waiting for the iframe to load and that is not how to use `waitForKeyElements() with an iframe`.

From [the *waitForKeyElements.js* source page](https://gist.github.com/BrockA/2625891), the parameters are:

```
selectorTxt,    /* Required: The jQuery selector string that
                    specifies the desired element(s).
                */
actionFunction, /* Required: The code to run when elements are
                    found. It is passed a jNode to the matched
                    element.
                */
bWaitOnce,      /* Optional: If false, will continue to scan for
                    new elements even after the first match is
                    found.
                */
iframeSelector  /* Optional: If set, identifies the iframe to
                    search.
                */
```

You need to specify `iframeSelector`.

Based on the question code, **a complete script** like this will work:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Site X, Auto-select imported products
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

waitForKeyElements ("#CDYN_126", deneme, false, "#WA2");

function deneme (jNode) {
    jNode.val ('1');
}
```